# how to reference itemTpl by its attribute myId in sencha touch

Tags: extjs

```
formPanel.add({
  xtype: 'list',
  store: store,
  itemTpl:'<div class="contact" myId="{id}"><strong>{title}</strong></div>',
  listeners:{
    itemtap:function(me,index,target){
      console.log("");
    }
  }
});
```

I want to display myId attribute value of itemtpl in itemtap function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this itemptap function, because it has more parameters.

```
listeners:{
    itemtap: function(list, index, target, record, evt) {
        console.log(record);
        console.log(record.get('id'));
        console.log(record.get('title'));
    }
}
```